# How would I find the velocity and angle at which at which a 2d dimensional projectile hits a target?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, computational-physics, projectile, software

I was basically trying to find the velocity $V$ and the angle $s$ at which a 2d projectile thrown hits a target located at the coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$. I tried solving for $V$ and $s$ both by hand and by using Python but the former I couldn't do because everything was getting quite convoluted and the latter wasn't giving me an output.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward to find the trajectory of the particle $\vec{r}(t)$. Once you find that you can find

$$\vec{v}(t_0)=\left.\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right|_{t_0}$$
where $t_0$ is the  collision time and can be found from
$$\vec{r}(t_0)=x_1\hat{i}+y_1\hat{y}$$
Once you find this angle can found from
$$\cos\theta=\hat{n}\cdot \vec{v}(t_0)$$
where $\hat{n}$ is normal vector at $(x_1,y_1)$ to the surface.